# blur the back ground image based on some condition in angular js

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a login page and if I click on the forgot password under the password button, a slider panel opens with information to recover the password. I need to blur the background image once this slider panel opens.

```
<div class="signinBackground" ng-click="signIn.closeForgotSlider($event)">
    <div class="col text-right col-top forgotEmailPassDiv">
        <a ng-click="signIn.forgotPassword($event)">{{'FORGOTPASSWORD'| translate}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I achieve this in angular?

Comment: use ng-class or ng-style for conditioning styles in css

Comment: try using backdrop . maybe that will help you out (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have following element for background image:

```
<div ng-class={'blurBg': showBlurBg}><img src=".."/></div>
```

You need to make below changes:

```
$scope.showBlurBg = true;//If you want to blug background
$scope.showBlurBg = false;//If you dont want to blug background
```

Add css to blur background:

```
.blurBg {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```